# Center of a mass of a hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

How can I show that position vector of the center of a mass of a hemisphere is $(0,0,\frac{3a}{8})$ where $a$ is radius of a hemisphere, $x$ and $y$ axis are laying on the base and $z$-axis is perpendicular to the base and is going through the center of the base, $P$? Is there some formula? I calculated tensor of inertia in a point $P$, can that help? Mass of a hemisphere is $M=\frac{2}{3} \pi a^3 \rho$ and $\rho$ is density.

Comment: You must have calculated inertia using $\int dm r^2$, where $r$ is the perpendicular dist. from an axis. Well, the position of center of mass is given by $\int dm \vec r$, where $\vec r$ is the position vector of an elementary mass $dm$. Maybe that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways

1. **Brute Force Computation.**  Compute the position of the center of mass using the following integral formula.
   $$
     \mathbf x_\mathrm{cm} = \frac{1}{M} \int d^3x\, \rho(\mathbf x)\mathbf x
   $$
   where $M$ is the total mass of the object, and $\rho$ is its mass density.  In cartesian coordinates $(x^1, x^2, x^3)$, this can be written as
   $$
     x^i_\mathrm{cm} = \frac{1}{M}\int dx^1\,dx^2\,dx^3\rho(x^1,x^2,x^3) x^i
   $$
2. **Symmetry Argument.**  Notice that the hemisphere exhibits rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis, and argue that the center of mass vector should respect this symmetry.  This can be argued rigorously by showing that if the mass density is invariant under a certain rotation, then so is the center of mass position.

**Note.** Even the brute force computation method can be made easier by making use of the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: The vector notation is intimidating... I would just say $\frac{1}{M} \int_0^a \rho A(x) x dx$.  Or at least I think that's right.

Comment: @AlanSE Hmmm well I'm not sure I understand your expression, but I assumed that since the OP mentions he has calculated the inertia tensor, he wouldn't be particularly intimidated by vector notation...

Answer (score 0):

For each slice of the hemisphere along the $z$ axis the mass fraction is

$${\rm d} m = \rho\, \pi\, r(z)^2\; {\rm d} z$$

with $r(z) = \sqrt{z (2a - z )}$ and the total mass $M=\int_0^a\, {\rm d} m $

Now the c.m. height from the $xy$ plane is defined by

$$  z_{cm} =\frac{1}{M} \int_0^a z\; \rho\, \pi\, r(z)^2\; {\rm d} z$$

with the result $z_{cm} = \frac{5}{8} a $ from the $xy$ axes, or $\frac{3}{8} a$ from the sphere center.

Comment: This does not address determining the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the center of mass, so it doesn't address the original question of how one can show that the center of mass lies on the axis of symmetry.  Also, your $z_\mathrm{cm}$ seems unequal to that given in the question.

Comment: @joshphysics $z_{cm}$ is what books have. It depends on it is measured from the center or the $xy$ plane.

Comment: @joshphysics the $xy$ coordinates of the cm is by inspection zero because it lies on the center of each (circular) slice.